# Can't access Ubuntu graphical user interface

Tags: 18.04, gui, tty

The problem is I can't access the Ubuntu graphical user interface.

I have two operating systems: Ubuntu and Windows 7 in the same computer. When I turn on the computer, I choose which OS I want to use.

[image: GRUB menu]

Normaly when I choose Ubuntu, it opens normally and I can use the graphical user interface.
But today when I tried to use Ubuntu, it demands me my login and password and then it's just the terminal that is open.

This is what is shown in screen after choosing Ubuntu:

[image: Photo of screen after choosing Ubuntu from GRUB menu]

After logging in, this is shown in the screen:

[image: Photo of screen after logging in]

I didn't have access to graphical user interface(GUI). Generally after choosing Ubuntu, this will be displayed:

[image: Ubuntu graphical user interface]

Also there's short message in the screen that says that there's a new version of Ubuntu 20.4. I wonder if I should update to solve the problem. How should I solve this problem? (I'm begginer in using Linux environment.)

Comment: Can you please add a photo of the terminal window which you are able to see?

Comment: i don't know how to do screen shot using command line and how to save the pic and tranfer it to wondows , but when  i open linux , it s just like i oppened Terminal  , and that  s its , i can use command lines and i can see the files i have in linux and their contents , but  dn't have LUbuntu Interface (the pic Obove ) please tell me for any other clarrification

Comment: Take a picture with your smartphone and transfer it to the device from which you wrote this question and add the photo :)

Comment: Yees , i tried to but when i click to add pics it dosen't downloaded !! can you pls tell me you email so i can send you the Captures ?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115431/discussion-between-technastic-tc-and-james).

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling `gdm3`:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gdm3
```

or start `gdm` manually from TTY:

```
sudo gdm3
```

or install `lightdm`:

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

or try to install drivers:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Answer (score -1):

try the following commands:

- first: this will display the target being used

  ```
  $ systemctl get-default
  ```
- second, you can actually run the follwing command to switch to the graphical-
  target

  ```
  $ systemctl isolate graphical-target
  ```